Request for instagram converstations list returns empty list despite valid access token
I am sending a GET request to retrieve an overview of my user conversations, following this documentation.
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.instagram.com/v21.0/$APP_SCOPED_USER_ID/conversations?platform=instagram&access_token=$LONG_ACCESS_TOKEN"                                                                    

Using the Acces Token debugger I have verified that my long-acccess token has the appropriate permissions:
instagram_business_basic, instagram_business_manage_messages, instagram_business_content_publish, instagram_business_manage_comments

It returns an empty list, even though I have conversations on the Instagram account:

{"data":[]}

It return reponse status 200, so I think the request is OK but I don't understand why the list of converstations is empty.
Complete output:
HTTP/2 200 
etag: "1050253aec7b29caff644806927dabfa81406eee"
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
vary: Origin
vary: Accept-Encoding
cross-origin-resource-policy: cross-origin
x-app-usage: {"call_volume":0,"cpu_time":0}
instagram-api-version: v21.0
access-control-allow-origin: *
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; preload; includeSubDomains
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
x-fb-request-id: AJDy8jjnwzoXsbaD81SmtVR
x-fb-trace-id: HY/Hc9Ie7Gw
x-fb-rev: 1018763301
x-stack: www
x-fb-debug: mX0wWU1Pk1etujdU1lsm1/gKHjgAlzKPS2B3sLbBjFtu8xUO0z6NOVizj5u+27ULdvNP5NvardPAZMvOULGr5g==
content-length: 11
date: Tue, 10 Dec 2024 19:35:31 GMT
x-fb-connection-quality: EXCELLENT; q=0.9, rtt=28, rtx=0, c=16, mss=1380, tbw=3420, tp=-1, tpl=-1, uplat=1367, ullat=0
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400

{"data":[]}g

